# Adding a session ID to a link for automatic session start

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I'm not sure if anything like this is even possible, but I was told that I need to make my site easier for specific end users.

At the moment, I am storing a session variable that a user types into a textbox. With their valid input, their session gets created and they get a little more functionality than the regular end users of the site.

I was wondering if it is possible to find a way to add someone's session variable to the end of a URL. This way we can email a link to one of our clients, they click it, and their session has automatically begun.

They already have the textbox to enter their code into, but I was told that it would be much easier for the users to just click a link that will start their session.

If this doesn't make sense, please let me know and I will try to explain it better. It's tough for me to wrap my mind around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default sessions expire (I think after 20 minutes) both for security reasons and to conserve system resources that otherwise would be dedicated to maintaining session state.

Any time you provide any sort of URL that allows one to bypass authentication, that opens a security hole.  It is up to you and your company to decide whether the benefits outweigh the risks.  Just keep in mind that anyone that sees the URL (even someone listening to the over-the-wire communication) can later use that URL to gain access.

If you do want to go that route, you may want to append something like a GUID that is associated with the user's account.  If an inbound URL contains an appropriate parameter with a GUID, try to lookup the user account from the GUID.  If you find the GUID, create a new session for the user.

Again, this does represent a major security risk.  Anyone with the special URL can act as the actual user.  Ensure you and your company fully understand that before proceeding.

Consider logging the IP address of sessions created using the special GUID so that you can at least detect patterns of abuse.  If users will usually access the system from a fixed IP address (e.g. if this is an Intranet application) you might consider locking the ability to use the special GUID to that IP address.  If they access the system e.g. from home with a different IP, just send them to the login page instead.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable explanation. If it was just me, I'd say let it be the way it is. I'll tell my boss what you just told me and hopefully he won't tell me to go ahead with it. :/ (I still have a feeling he will...)

Comment: Yeah he said security isn't really an issue because we don't have any crucial information in this site. So I have to figure out how to use this session variable the right way. So far I can't get it to work right.